# design issue after adding this html in Text box

Tags: html

I have an text in my DB have an column and it constains value like this

```
<br /><style><br /><!--<br />
```

now when I am trying to display that value in the text box the entire  design page is getting affected.
my design looks like this initially .

```
 <tr>
                             <td width="590" colspan="2">
                              <div id="divBio" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 0px; overflow: auto;
                               width: 400px; height: 50px" >
                              </div>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtBio" Style="overflow: auto" onchange="fnUpdate();" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="400px" Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            </tr>
```

after getting data and showing in page

```
 <tr>
                             <td width="590" colspan="2">
                              <div id="divBio" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 0px; overflow: auto;
                               width: 400px; height: 50px"><br /><style><br /><!--<br /></div>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtBio" Style="overflow: auto" onchange="fnUpdate();" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="400px" Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;style&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;!--&lt;br /&gt;</td>
                            </tr>
```

have any idea why my html design changes once this data is shown in text box

```
<br /><style><br /><!--<br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the start of a comment into your page so the rest of the page gets commented out. You should be very careful when inserting data you don't control into a page. An opening comment is pretty innocent. Suppose a hacker makes an entry in your database with a script tag and some malicious script in it.

You need to html encode your data.

```
<%: db.myData %> // note the colon

// is short-hand for

<%= Server.HtmlEncode(db.myData) %>
```